# ExtJS surface and sprite creation functions

Tags: javascript, function, extjs, extjs4, drawing

I am trying to create an ExtJS app to create surfaces based on an XML file and later be able to add sprites on these surfaces via the mouse. I am having a bit of trouble with the actual functions that are to create the surfaces and sprites via parameters that can be gotten from the sources enumerated earlier. My objects I create are coming back undefined when I check tham for value in the JS console. I do not have any errors or warnings in the JS that it reports. Here is the code:

```
Ext.ns('myNameSpace');//create namespace to hold all variables
    myNameSpace = {
        init: function(){//initialize namespace
            function surfaceCreator(name){//create surface based on parameter
                var name = Ext.create('Ext.draw.Component', {
                    viewBox: false
                });
                return name;
            }
            function spriteCreator(surfaceName,sprite,posX,posY){//draw sprite based on parameters
                var sprite = Ext.create('Ext.draw.Sprite', {
                    type: 'circle',
                    x: posX,
                    y: posY,
                    radius: 25,
                    surface: surfaceName.surface,
                    fill: '#cc5'
                });sprite.show(true);
            }
            var mySurface = 'mySurface';//this could be an xml value
            var myCircle = 'myCircle';//this could be determined by numbering each one that is created.
            var myActualSurface = surfaceCreator(mySurface);//call function to create surface and return surface name as an object
            spriteCreator(myActualSurface,myCircle,20,20);//call function to create sprite on specified surface. Also, I could use the mouse coordinates to determine where the sprite should be drawn and make this trigger on 'click'.
            var myWin = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {// Create a window to house the surfaces
                width: 800,
                resizeable: false,
                height: 600,
                layout: 'fit',
                items: myActualSurface//This seems to be undefined somehow and I'm not sure why, as it is defined up above.
            }).show();
        }
    }
Ext.onReady(myNameSpace.init,myNameSpace);//render namespace when webpage is ready.
```

If I could get some second opinion on what might be going on here I would be very happy. If someone has a solution(odds are I'm simply using something incorrectly) I would be ecstatic. Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem here is the "surface" property, refer : http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.draw.Sprite

You can add sprite to the surface using following notation:

```
surfaceName.add(sprite);
```

**OR**

```
var sprite = Ext.create('Ext.draw.Sprite', {
                    type: 'circle',
                    x: posX,
                    y: posY,
                    radius: 25,
                    // surface: surfaceName.surface, >> omit this line
                    fill: '#cc5'
                });
{
xtype:'drawcomponent',
items:[sprite]
}
```